# Sharing System State Information Across Several Processes: Static Class | Extern Header | Class with Static Members

Tags: c++, linux, embedded, shared-memory, atomic

**The System:** Nvidia Jetson TX2

**The OS:**     Linux Ubuntu 16.04

**Language:**   C++11

---

**The Problem:**
I am designing an embedded system that will have several threads forked from 1 process to perform various tasks. The parent process will be something like *SystemController* and will receive IPC commands from a Bluetooth Communication Program. At that point, a thread will be forked to execute the given task: ie. take a panoramic photo.

T1. Communicate over bluetooth

T2. Take Pictures

T3. Process Images and Upload

T4. *--Future Functionality--*

I need a way to have a static *System State* that is readable and writeable by all of the threads as a way to indicate status between the threads. So when the thread that is taking photos is capturing, it can set a state variable for the parent process to communicate back to the Bluetooth Process via IPC.

---

**Considerations:**

The options I placed in the title (Static Class | Extern Header | Class with Static Members) are there as pointers to where I am thinking at the moment. I was thinking that a class with static atomic variables might be a good option (example below). In this case, I was thinking about having a *state monitor* thread that periodically checks and updates the variables in the StateMonitor class.

```
class StateMonitor
{
public:
   // Functions called by other processes
   bool getConnectedToWifi();
   bool getBLEPeripheralPaired();
   bool getCurrentlyTakingPhotos();
   void updateBLEPeripheralPaired();

   // Functions called by StateMonitor Process
   void updateConnectedToWifiStatus();
   void updateWifiNetworkConnectedTo();
   void updatedBatteryVoltage();

private:
   static std::atomic<bool> connectedToWifi;
   static std::atomic<bool> bLEPeripheralPaired;
   static std::atomic<bool> currentlyTakingPhotos;
   static std::atomic<string> wifiNetworkConnectedTo;
   static std::atomic<double> batteryVoltageLevel;
}
```

---

**The Question:**

What would be a great way to share system state information across all of the threads forked from the system control process? For example: So that the thread taking photos can be made aware when the thread that is spinning the device is complete and thus needs to take another picture?

**Edit**

My approach currently is using a singleton-designed state class that acts as a "database" of state values. All threads have access to the state values and can update.

Comment: `The OS: Linux Ubuntu 16.04` so you have all the [C++11 threads and mutex](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex) and even [posix mutexes](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_mutex_lock.html)? Use C++ api designed just for that....

Comment: Yes I do have access to all of the c++11 Thread and Mutex libraries along with posix IPC. My question was more focused on the design of a shared system state. However, upon second read of my question I realize I did not state that explicit. Thank you for the clarification @KamilCuk

Comment: Not sure what do you mean by "static class", or how do you expect to communicate using only "external header", but having a state fields in the shared memory is definitely a good idea. But a way of representing these state fields is **up to you** - it is required much more information about your project for make the selection *objective*.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I have an embedded system that have several Hardware devices (Arduino with stepper and sensors, RGB camera, Thermal camera, Lidar etc.). I am designing the software that is going to run the system. I need to communicate via bluetooth to a user. I need to capture images. I need to communicate with the Arduino. I need to process data and upload. I am looking for what would be considered an industry standard for IPC in this kind of situation.

Comment: There is no "industry standard" which covers **all embedded systems**. Use those IPC mechanisms which is provided by the OS you are programming for. Just a hint: shared memory is the most tricky IPC mechanism. E.g., `atomic<string>` most likely won't be work as you expect. If your OS provides some messaging IPC mechanism, it is better to use it instead.

Comment: @Tsyvarev That makes sense given that systems and problems vary massively. Let me ask another question along this vein. Why would I use an IPC mechanism when I can just use a class with static members like in my code example above?

Comment: Well, if a reader process works in a polling mode (regularly call `get*` method) you can maintain the state flags as `atomic<bool>` variables. But: 1. Accessing `atomic<string>` would imply locks. An I am unsure that the compiler will implement them correctly for your OS. 2. Methods of your class (you probably want to make them *static*), intended for different processes, should be implemented in the different source files, each of which should be compiled into corresponded process. 3. How do you enforce to place the static members to the shared memory? Is there a special switch for compiler?

Comment: @Tsyvarev Yes you actually made me realize the confusion I was having in my head about what I was actually talking about. I was thinking about inter-thread communication and writing as if I was talking about inter-process communication. I really just need to refactor my whole question because I am really asking about IPC between 2 processes which I can do as a Msgqueue and then inter-thread communication which I can do with static members of a class I believe.

Comment: If you have a full blown ubuntu OS, I would go with writing multiple small programs for each peripheral you want to support, and connect them using files fifos and a simple bash script. The bigger you go, the more problems you will have. Is there a reason why the RGB camera software should be aware of thermal camera software? There is no point in designing a "global central communication interface". 1. It already exists - `udev`, `/proc`, `/dev` etc. and 2. keep it simple.

Comment: `that the thread taking photos can be made aware when the thread that is spinning the device is complete and thus needs to take another picture?` - connect the "spinning the device recognizing" program that outputs a newline on stdout on each spinning recognizing with bash scripting + program taking photos, so that the program taking photos is run each time a newline from the first program is outputted.

Comment: @KamilCuk that is insightful! I was learning towards an interface layer because I want the User-Device-Interface (ie BLE)  to be a standalone process for reliability. This in turn would Communicate with a Device-Hardware-Interface that is in charge of spinning up either the Threads or Processes necessary initiate a hardware action: ie. spin and take photos and Lidar scan. so the Device-Hardware-Interface would be responsible for coordinating Hardware Events and reporting back to the User-Device-Interface. Does that seem like a reasonable approach?

Comment: Sounds like a good design, but the key parts are missing. "Communicate"? _How_ communicate? So you have a program that handles BLE. In case of user request "scan TV channels" that program outputs on stdout "scan TV chanells". That's all. Simple BLE->stdout. Then you have a bash script which matches the line from stdout and runs `dvbscan` in case of that particular line. Then you have a program that transfers the input from stdin back to the user. The "connections" are done using bash scripts file descriptor redirections. Write programs that do one job only and do it good.